# Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat - Unable to find valid certification path

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have an interesting problem I have yet to find a solution for.  I have a Spring Boot application that is attempting to connect to a 3rd party API.  When I run this application locally using the embedded Tomcat server, attempts to connect to this 3rd party API fail with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://<third party API endpoint>": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; 
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I've imported the certificate for my 3rd party API into my local JDK's keystore and if I run this application on another application server like Weblogic then it executes as expected.  I just can't seem to get the Spring Boot embedded Tomcat server to behave properly.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to test against Jetty or Glassfish as well? I've seen certificate issues in the past when using Oracle's JDK vs some other like OpenJDK or IBMs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my issue was a missing 3rd level intermediate certificate that I need to get through my corporate firewall.  In order to figure this out I enabled SSL debugging so I could find the missing certificate.  I accomplished this by adding the following VM argument to my application:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=SSL
```

Once I saw there was a 3rd level certificate, I imported that certificate into my JDK and **poof**...problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check that your java_home and Java.exe in your path point to the same installation. Usually we have multiple jres and a lot of the time certs get installed into a different jre then being run. Maybe inspect the process and make sure it's using the same jre as has the certs (maybe even try jconsole to verify)